# MYSQL insert form- insert 1 of 3 possible options from dependent select boxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I have been searching for an answer to this for about an hour and can't find what I am looking for...

I have 3 dependent select boxes on a INSERT form.(drop_1, drop_2, drop_3) Each of their values (int) represent the same field in the database called `category`.

I am looking for a way to choose only the highest value of the three as the value that gets inserted into the `category` field.

Here is what I have been trying (obviously doesn't work):

```
$drop_1 = ($_POST['drop_1']);
$drop_2 = ($_POST['drop_2']);
$drop_3 = ($_POST['drop_3']);
$category = max($drop_1, $drop_2, $drop_3);
```

This works only if I select an option from each of the 3 boxes, but if I select an option from only 1 or 2 of the boxes the form gets submitted to the DB with blank values.

Comment: can you show html  of that form.

Comment: Please show the form so we can see the value choices.

Comment: possible SQL injection. You should learn using `mysql_real_escape_string()` before inserting into query.

Comment: On my form processor script I am sanitizing the $category by using: $category = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($category));

Is this effective or should I sanitize both the $drop_x and $category variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your php seems fine:

```
<?php

$_POST['drop_1'] = 100;
$_POST['drop_2'] = null;

$drop_1 = ($_POST['drop_1']);
$drop_2 = ($_POST['drop_2']);
$drop_3 = ($_POST['drop_3']);
$category = max($drop_1, $drop_2, $drop_3);

echo $category;
```

would output:

```
100
```

so, problem is with the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$drop_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop_1']);
$drop_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop_2']);
$drop_3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop_3']);
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (category) 
            SELECT GREATEST('$drop_1', '$drop_2', '$drop_3') as new_cat ";
```